# can we have a placeholder/FAQ/feedback mechanism for questions that we know the community is going to close?

Tags: discussion

Once again, we have a [why doesn't the US do Communism](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/53048/why-is-america-so-averse-to-socialism) question.  It's by a new poster, and yes, all the usual reasons are going to be trotted out before closing.  It may even be closed without any comments, and it already has been downvoted (-2 after 47 minutes) without any comments.

The last previous such was only about 2 weeks ago.  On the face of it, it's not an obviously stupid question.  To a new contributor this most likely comes off as rather unfriendly and abrupt from the SE.Politics community.

Note that I don't disagree with the intent to close.  However, is there a mechanism by which we would once and for all record the reason to close this particular type of question?  Then we could point the OP to it and explain ("FAQ: why Communism in US questions get closed").

One possible form might be a locked Community Question and new ones would be closed off as duplicates.  **I don't know**, I am only asking if we have a way to communicate better on reasons for closure on frequently asked questions that are otherwise reasonable, but not suitable for this site.

BTW, please refrain from dive-bombing the OP's question just because I've asked about it.  I've seen it happen before, from Meta on another SE site, the community should be better than this.

Comment: The linked question talks about socialism, not communism

Comment: @coredump So?  it's tagged communism as well, is pretty much a to a similar question 2 weeks re communism and Divisibans link to a *communist* question gets upvoted.  Anyway, that has little to do with the subject of this post which is how do we explain to noobs the closure of frequently closed questions, rather than turning them off with clique-ish behavior.

Answer (score -1):

If the question is on-topic in principle but poorly phrased (the one you link to is rather prototypical, being a loaded question)

> the intelligentsia seems to completely ignore the fact that socialistic ideas have worked in big parts of the world and the problem is that they DELIBERATELY ignore it. why?

then it could be asked separately by someone else. But consider what exactly is this question asking. "socialistic ideas" is poorly/hardly defined, as is "intelligentsia". (Don't tell me that Marxism has been completely ignored in US academia for example, because [it hasn't been](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/buttigieg-father-marxist/). This without getting to [extreme] right-wing view that most [or even all] of US academia is Marxist.) So this is quite a difficult question to focus properly. What exactly of "socialistic ideas" do you (or the OP of that q) actually claim are being ignored by US "intelligentsia", and who exactly falls in that bin?

So, I'm all for reference/canonical questions, but this doesn't seem to me like a topic that one could easily make such a question for. There are some near-duplicates that are more suitable for that kind of treatment, e.g. why communism hasn't succeeded in the US, or why it has a bad rap there in general, etc.

- [What does the US have to gain by other countries not being socialist or communist?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-the-us-have-to-gain-by-other-countries-not-being-socialist-or-communis)
- [Why is communism considered as evil (like fascism and nazism) in the United States?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26145/why-is-communism-considered-as-evil-like-fascism-and-nazism-in-the-united-stat)
- [Why did communism not succeed in the USA?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/52660/why-did-communism-not-succeed-in-the-usa)

Etc. Never mind all the [democratic socialism](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39009/democratic-socialism-vs-social-democracy/39010?r=SearchResults&s=16|9.6247#39010) (usually [in re Bernie](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/38967/why-is-it-that-bernie-sanders-is-always-called-a-socialist)) questions that often touch on the negative connotation of "socialism" in the US, at least in some circles. So it's hard to say this topic hasn't been addressed, in general. Maybe there's some angle that's missing coverage, but it's not obvious to me what that is.

A bit more search finds [some complaints](https://mronline.org/2020/02/06/the-marginalization-of-marxism-in-academia/), I'm guessing for Marxists, that Marx is too marginalized in US academia nowadays. I guess one could peruse that and try to formulate a more focused question. On the flip side, there are [those](https://www.econlib.org/archives/2015/03/the_prevalence_1.html) on the right-wing side that argue that there's *still* too *much* Marxism in US academia, even after considering the relative low percentage of self-identification. So it's hard to say how one could make an objective question out of this, if the focus or premise is that there is too little or too much of that...

Also note the last comment from the OP (in re the "evil" question link)

> @divibisan thank you very much. That does answer my query to a large extent. – shashank shekhar singh May 3 at 8:10

Now if you propose that we have some duplicate/oft-asked questions list that newbies would be warned about, e.g. in a banner message... I'm not sure that is feasible without that kind of banner/list becoming overwhelming. (I know that on biology SE they now have a banner message in re Covid-19 questions, but I don't know of other similar examples. [Actually, it seems they [ha*d* a banner](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4061/bannering-the-main-site-for-coronavirus) on that, but it seems they took it down in the meantime, or at least it's not showing up for me anymore.) SE does has have an auto-search feature that is continuously updated while someone types in the their question. That cannot catch everything that is a [near] duplicate, of course.